# How to remove the light blue frame in gojs's example "productionProcess"?

Tags: html, frame, gojs

The url of the "productionProcess" example is:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/productionProcess.html

The process chart is placed into one div whose id is "myDiagramDiv". Whenever you click any place with the left mouse in the div, a light blue frame just around the div will appear.

My question is how to remove the light blue frame around the div "myDiagramDiv"; is it possible to do so through javascript or by setting certain property of gojs?. [image: The light blue of the div has been circled in the picture]

Comment: It is called outline. When you focus/click on any element, browser will add a blue line. add the following css. It will remove this outline:
`* {
    outline: 0 none;
}`

Comment: @Shuvo Great, it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the browser.  If really you want to change it, apply this CSS:

```
#myDiagramDiv * {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); /* mobile webkit */
}
```

But the general recommendation is to replace the focus indication with something else.  How is up to you.
http://www.outlinenone.com/

More discussion is at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/HTMLInteraction.html#HTMLFocusOnDiagrams and 
https://forum.nwoods.com/t/removing-the-blue-focus-border-of-the-diagram/5354

Comment: Another excellent solution! Thank you for your kind help, Walter Northwoods!